# Searching against a partial match in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Tab-A contains a two columns. Column 1 is website domains, column 2 is filled with a formula that should output emails found in Tab-B:

```
backpacks.com         / FORMULA TO FIND EMAIL FROM TAB-B 
buy.bags.io           / FORMULA TO FIND EMAIL FROM TAB-B
shop.plasticbags.net  / FORMULA TO FIND EMAIL FROM TAB-B
bags.org              / FORMULA TO FIND EMAIL FROM TAB-B
```

Tab-B contains two columns. Column 1 is emails, column 2 is email domains:

```
admin@backpacks.com     / backpacks.com 
hi@bags.io              / bags.io
hello@plasticbags.net   / plasticbags.net
support@bags.org        / bags.org
```

For each domain in Tab A, I want to search through the email domains in Tab B and see if there is a partial match. For example, "bags.io" is partial match of "buy.bags.io". I extracted the email domains from the email address to match searching easier, but you could also search through the entire email address for  a partial match if you know how.

If there is a match I want to output it's associated email. If there is no match I want to put a blank cell.

I've been trying to figure this out using Vlookup and others but I just can't get it. How can I get this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($E$1:$E$4)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$1:$E$4,A1))),1)),"")
```

It iterates the one column with the domains and returns the partial match row to the INDEX which returns the email.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you can use VLOOKUP then you could use:

```
VLOOKUP("*"& lookup value  &"*" , table array , column number, FALSE)
```

Where `"*"` is wildcard.

`"*"& lookup value`: then it accept other words infront of your lookup value.

`"*"& lookup value`: then it accept other words after your lookup value.

`"*"& lookup value &"*"`: accept words on both sides of your lookup value.

Happy lookup :)!

Answer (score 1):

Well... I have a much more complicated answer than Scott. For posterity, here it is!

1. In Tab-A Column B, I created a helper column that counts the number of `.` in the domain
2. In Tab-A Column C & D & E, I created a formula to return each "chunk" of the domain.
3. In Tab-A Column F, I created a formula that returns the email based on two searches: combining Column C&D, and if that returns no value, then combining Column D&E.

What this does is searches for multiple combinations of the chunks of the domain rather than searching for a partial match from the email address.

In `B1` `=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))`

In `C1` `=IF(A1=0,"",TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE("."&A1,".",REPT(" ",99)),(B1+1)*99),99)))`

In `D1` `=IF(A1=0,"",TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE("."&A1,".",REPT(" ",99)),(B1)*99),99)))`

In `E1` `=IF(A1=0,"",TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE("."&A1,".",REPT(" ",99)),(B1-1)*99),99)))`

In `F1` `=INDEX('Tab-B'!A1:A4,IFNA(MATCH("*"&C1&"."&D1&"*",'Tab-B'!B1:B4,0)<>"",MATCH("*"&D1&"."&E1&"*",'Tab-B'!B1:B4,0)))`

Allow me to say that Scott's solution is a helluva lot more elegant!
[image]